# Android runtime code injection / method hooking with Java Reflection

Tags: android, reflection, runtime, code-injection

I am currently researching on runtime injection techniques for Android. Is there any way to achieve a similar result as the Xposed Framework with Java Reflections? As far as I have seen, there is just the possibility to call methods of another apps or to read its fields using reflections. However, my goal is to hook into method calls to inject custom code. Is this anyhow possible with Java reflection? For example to load my own classes/dex files into other apps that change a certain parameter before a method is invoked.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: "there is just the possibility to call methods of another apps or to read its fields using reflections" -- you can't even do that, short of having root and doing some fancy footwork. One process cannot access the address space of another process.

Comment: the use case is on a rooted device - I was able to do the actions I mentioned on an emulator / rooted device. Another possibility, as far as I know would be to debug the application with JDB and load a custom dex into the application via reflection since it is possible to execute expressions via the 'eval' command in JDB